# Nunit how to use parallelizable with order?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have 12 test files/classes in my selenium test suite, each file/class with a bunch of individual tests of a certain category(individual tests in the files I want to execute normally in order, one after the other)

Currently, these 12 test files execute sequentially, but I want to implement parallel execution, to a degree. This is what I want to do:

> Files 1 to 3 needs to run one after the other
>
> Files 4 to 7 needs to run one after the other
>
> File 8 can run in parallel with the others
>
> Files 9 and 10 needs to run one after the other
>
> File 11 can run in parallel with the others
>
> File 12 can run in parallel with the others

Basically I want to split these tests into 6 different packages that run in parallel with eachother, but the tests in each of those packages run in order, for my example I'd want tests 1,4,8,9,11,12 to start at the same time, after test 1 is done test 2 starts, when test 4 is done test 5 starts, when test 9 is done test 10 starts, etc. When tests 8, 11, and 12 are done, they're just done

I have attached a picture that better illustrates what I mean:[image]

How would I go about doing this in NUnit? I have messed around with parallelizable but I have not found a way to incorporate order along with it.

Comment: Tests should be able to run completely independent of each other, and should be able to run in any order.

Comment: I understand that, but I have like 30 different packages with like 200 individual tests, and almost all of them rely on some sort of setup (like signing up and logging in), I can't imagine it would be good to sign up a brand new account for every single test that requires an account?

Answer (score 0):

In the development of NUnit, we made a distinction between **order** of tests and **dependencies**. The two are, of course, related but not precisely the same. Ordering can be used to emulate certain kinds of simple dependencies, but not all of them. Your case falls outside of what is possible without a true implementation of test dependencies.

When `[Order]` is used with parallel test cases, it only affects the order **in which the tests are started**. If you have a test with `[Order(1)]`, it starts first. But if there is an available thread to run it, a test with `[Order(2)]` may start immediately afterwords. Consequently, `OrderAttribute` is not very useful with parallel tests.

Assuming that each "file" 1 thourgh 12 is an NUnit `TestFixture` (please confirm) there isn't a way to specify that some subset of them should run sequentially but in parallel with other fixtures. If it's possible to reorganize your code in such a way that each of the six groups is a `TestFixture`, then I think we can come up with a workaround.

UPDATE

I understand now that your classes (files) are test fixtures, that is, they are classes containing test cases. (It's useful to learn and use the NUnit jargon if you want to talk about NUnit. :-)

NUnit allows you to designate test fixtures that must run by themselves (non-parallel) or in parallel with other test fixtures. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow you to specify selectively which fixtures may run in parallel with other fixtures. That would be a great enhancement for sure!

So... to achieve what you want, you would need to combine 1, 2 and 3 into a single class. Same for 4+5+6+7 and 9+10. You would then annotate each of the six classes with `[Parallelizable]`. This will cause them to run in parallel with one another as well as with any other classes you have in the run. The individual tests in each class will run sequentially.

So, it depends on whether you can combine the classes as I described. If the classes to be combined have significantly different setup among themselves, it might not be possible. If they are merely separate for convenience, then it's a judgement call for you to make. Personally, I would say that organizing fixtures to make use of the capabilities of the framework is the right way to go.

Comment: It's certainly possible to reorganize my code in that way, I am not currently using testFixture at the moment but I have in the past, I removed it because it didn't seem to make any difference at the time

Comment: It's not possible to have tests in NUnit without having TestFixtures! Any class containing annotated tests is a Test Fixture. Using the `[TestFixture]` attribute is what is optional. My confusion was because you seemed to be avoiding calling them test fixtures. See updateed answer.